# @font-face not recognized

Tags: css, fonts, transfer, embedded-fonts

Ok I have my site up so far but the two fonts I used are not showing up. I transferred the fonts and put them in the same folder as my webpages. I also used @font-face in css (styless.css). I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Website: http://envycosmetics.zxq.net/TestSite/webpages/index.html

Comment: There is not a single @font-face rule on the site. Are you sure you have added them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at styless.css, and I can't see where you used @font-face. Make sure you do it like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: FontName; src: url('path/to/font.otf'); }
```

Then call it like this:

```
#navBar { font-family: FontName, sans-serif; }
```

Also, don't forget to call another font for browsers that don't support @font-face, as shown in `#navBar` values.

Comment: Ok its called now, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

> I also used @font-face in css (styless.css)

No... no, you didn't.